Cookies are not being set in the browser with express
Iam working on creating a web application in express and react , I have a login controller, on successful login I am returning a res and sending the cookie, I am able to see the cookie in the response under the network tab, But they are not being set in the browser also on http false they are not even accessible through js. please help what is the issue.
Here is the code:
I tried various solution from youtube and sites but not working
const Login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        console.log("fields", password, username);
        if (!username || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "All fields are required"
            });
        }

        const user = await userSchema.findOne({ name: username });
        console.log("user", user);
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "Username doesn't exist"
            });
        }

        console.log("passwords", password, user.password);

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        console.log("passwordMatch", passwordMatch);
        if (!passwordMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Password is incorrect"
            });
        }

        const payload = {
            name: username,
            id: user._id
        };

        const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "2h" });

        user.token = token;
        user.password = undefined;

        const options = {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), 
            httpOnly: false,
            sameSite: 'None', 
            secure: true, 
            path: '/', 
        };

        console.log("token", token);
        return res.cookie("token", token, options).status(200).json({
            success: true,
            token,
            user,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Internal server error",
            error: error
        });
    }
}


So you are making cross-origin request from the client side, yes? Have you set the credentials option / withCredentials flag in your request options?
